# Unable to print in both ascending and descending range in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create an `if else` rule in a for loop, but currently the values only print if the start value is less than the end value. I want the range to print in descending order if the start value is greater than the end value.

I've tried a few different options, but ideally I'm trying to create the code using only two for loops.

```
for i in range(x,y+1):
    if (x<=y):
      print(i) 
    else:
     for i in range(y,x,-1):
      print(i)
count_odd = 0 
count_even = 0 
for n in range(x,y+1):
        if   n%2==0: 
             count_even = count_even+1 
        else: 
             count_odd = count_odd+1 
print("Number of even numbers :",count_even)
print("Number of odd numbers :",count_odd)
```

Answer (score 3):

Put a condition in your code if `x<y` and use the `range` accordingly either ascending or descending order:

```
x = 10
y = 2
count_odd = 0 
count_even = 0 
if x < y:
    for n in range(x,y+1):
        if n%2==0: 
            count_even = count_even+1 
        else: 
            count_odd = count_odd+1 
else:
    for n in range(x, y-1, -1):
        if n%2==0: 
            count_even = count_even+1 
        else: 
            count_odd = count_odd+1 

print("Number of even numbers :",count_even)
print("Number of odd numbers :",count_odd)
```

Output:

```
Number of even numbers : 5                                                                                                            
Number of odd numbers : 4
```

**Edit**

And your intial `for` loop should be:

```
if (x<=y):
    for i in range(x,y+1):
        print(i) 
else:
    for i in range(x,y-1,-1):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle them differently and call the particular function once the condition hits. Here's an example.

```
x = 1
y = 10


def descOrder(x,y):
    count_even = 0
    count_odd = 0
    for i in range(x, y-1, -1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            count_even = count_even + 1
        else:
            count_odd += 1
        print(i)
    print ("Even:",count_even, "Odd:",count_odd)


def asceOrder(x, y):
    count_even = 0
    count_odd = 0
    for i in range(x ,y+1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            count_even += 1
        else:
            count_odd += 1
        print(i)
    print ("Even:",count_even, "Odd:",count_odd)


if x > y:
    descOrder(x, y)
else:
    asceOrder(x, y)
```